# Python - Extract specific items from nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, cryptocurrency

Working on a little project and I may be in over my head. Using the CoinMarketCap API, I am trying to understand how to parse through their results to pull out just specific pieces of the returned value.

As an example:

```
  result = {'status': {'timestamp': '2021-02-22T00:04:51.978Z', 'error_code': 0, 'error_message': None, 'elapsed': 46, 'credit_count': 1, 'notice': None}, 'data': {'1INCH': {'id': 8104, 'name': '1inch', 'symbol': '1INCH', 'slug': '1inch', 'cmc_rank': 83, 'last_updated': '2021-02-22T00:03:09.000Z', 'quote': {'BTC': {'price': 8.793673178965842e-05, 'volume_24h': 4010.9008604493424, 'percent_change_1h': 1.77689058, 'percent_change_24h': -3.76351861, 'percent_change_7d': -19.9798068, 'percent_change_30d': 66.4333541, 'market_cap': 12615.667000751586, 'last_updated': '2021-02-22T00:03:02.000Z'}}}}}
```

I am unable to figure out how to extract the 'symbol', 'cmc_rank', and 'market_cap' values from this variable. What is the proper approach to doing so?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution, it should give you what you're looking for:

```
symbol     = result['data']['1INCH']['symbol']
cmc_rank   = result['data']['1INCH']['cmc_rank']
market_cap = result['data']['1INCH']['quote']['BTC']['market_cap']
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
print(result["data"]["1INCH"]["symbol"])
print(result["data"]["1INCH"]["cmc_rank"])
print(result["data"]["1INCH"]["quote"]["BTC"]["market_cap"])
```

Answer (score 1):

The "{}" indicate a python dict (dictionary) -- (square brackets [] would be a list, and parentheses () would be a tuple). Dicts can also be nested (same with lists and tuples)

In this case, you have a nested dictionar(ies). It's helpful to do some indentation...

```
result = {
'status': {
    'timestamp': '2021-02-22T00:04:51.978Z', 
    'error_code': 0, 
    'error_message': None, 'elapsed': 46, 'credit_count': 1, 'notice': None}, 
'data': {
    '1INCH': {
       'id': 8104, 'name': '1inch', 'symbol': '1INCH', 'slug': '1inch', 'cmc_rank': 83, 'last_updated': '2021-02-22T00:03:09.000Z', 
        'quote': {
            'BTC': {
                'price': 8.793673178965842e-05, 'volume_24h': 4010.9008604493424, 'percent_change_1h': 1.77689058, 'percent_change_24h': -3.76351861, 'percent_change_7d': -19.9798068, 'percent_change_30d': 66.4333541, 'market_cap': 12615.667000751586, 'last_updated': '2021-02-22T00:03:02.000Z'}}}}}
```

The part to the left of the colon (:) in a dict is the **key** and the part to the right is the value.

So in the example you gave: `result['data']['1INCH']['symbol']` would give you the value of symbol and `result['data']['1INCH']['quote']['BTC']['market_cap']` would give you the value of market cap.

**HOWEVER**, this will only work if the keys don't change. In this case, it looks like the result is coming back with the symbol ('1INCH') as the key. Same with the currency ('BTC'). If you are always expecting '1INCH' and 'BTC' then you can hard code it. On the other hand, if the symbol and/or currency changes you would want to (a) store variables and use those instead (e.g. symbol='1INCH' .... result = x.query(symbol).... result['data'][symbol].....) OR (2) get the keys or (3) loop.

To get a list of the keys of any dictionary -- in this example, the keys of the dictionary 'data' : `dkeys = list(result['data'].keys())` ... you can then check the length with `len(dkeys)` and/or access the key with numbers (since it's a list) `dkeys[0]`. So, something like `result['data'][dkeys[0]]...`

Or you could loop - which would be great if you have multiple results:

```
#the .items() method will return 2 values - the key and value for each entry
for k, v in result['data'].items():
  #k would be the symbol in this case and v is the dictionary represented by that key
  market_cap = v['quote']['BTC']['market_cap']
  #note if there are multiple symbols here, it would overwrite market_cap...
```